# Как убрать фокус с edittext?

Tags: java, android, xml

Как можно убрать фокус с элемента edittext при старте активити. То есть при старте активити у меня выскакивает клавиатура - чего мне не надо.
Имею такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="com.example.jack.myapplication.MessagesActivity"
 tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_messages">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_horizontal"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:max="100" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ololo">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>




    <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="9"-->
        <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom">-->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_edit_message"
                android:inputType="text"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
                android:onClick="onClick_Send"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />

        </LinearLayout>
    <!--</LinearLayout>-->


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В манифесте для Layout, в котором находится Ваш EditText нужно указать

```
   android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732761/how-to-avoid-automatically-appear-android-keyboard-when-activity-start%20%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C), есть 2 варианта:

Первый программно:
  `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

Второй через манифест:

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    >
```

Comment: Ни работает ни то, ни другое

Comment: Попробуйте задать свойство android:focusableInTouchMode="true" в LinearLayout и RelativeLayout